# Ring homomorphism between commutative rings whose kernel has only nilpotent elements

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $f: A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism of commutative rings such that $\ker f$ is contained in the nilradical. Hence the induced continuous map $f^* :  \operatorname{Spec} B \to  \operatorname{Spec} A$ has dense image in $ \operatorname{Spec} A$. My question is : how to show that for every minimal prime ideal $P$ in $A$, there is a prime ideal $Q$ in $B$ such that $f^{-1}(Q)=P$ ?

Comment: Localize at $P$.

Comment: @Mohan: could you please elaborate on your comment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

If you localise at a *minimal* prime ideal $\mathfrak p$, the local ring $A_{\mathfrak p}$ has a single prime ideal, and the ring $B_{\mathfrak p}$ will necessarily have all its prime ideals above $\,\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}$, *unless* $\,B_{\mathfrak p}=\{0\}$.

Can you prove this is not the case?

Comment: I thought about it ... I can see that if $B_P$ were zero , then $A\setminus P$ would have an element in $ker f$, hence nilpotent , which can't be the case since the every nilpotent is contained in the intersection of minimal primes ... so $B_P$ is not the zero ring ... but I can't quite see how the conclusion that every prime ideal of $B_P$ lies above $PA_P$ gives my claim ?

Comment: @misao: Consider the commutative diagram \begin{array}{ccc}A\!&\!\to\!&\! B\\ \downarrow\!&&\!\downarrow\\A_{\mathfrak p}\!&\!\to\!& B_{\mathfrak p}\end{array}

Comment: P is a prime of A, what does $B_p$ mean? Image of a prime is not necessarily prime.

Comment: @XipanXiao: It is simply the ring of fractions of $B$ w.r.t. the multiplicative system $f(A\setminus\mathfrak p)$, which is isomorphic to $B\otimes_A A_{\mathfrak p}$

Comment: For your first question: not necessarily. I don't have a counterexample in mind at the moment, bt it shouldn't be hard to find one. Your second question is not very clear to me: how are defined $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Thanks I got your proof now: since the kernel is contained in $p$, if we denote the multiplicative set $S=A\setminus p$, the image $f(S)$ is a multiplicative set not containing $0$. So $f(S)^{-1}B$ is non-zero, and any of its prime, corresponds to a prime of $B$ away from $f(S)$, pulls back to a prime of $A$, contained in $p$.

Comment: That's perfectly explained!